# How to load JSON into @Html.Helper SelectList() in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, json, model-view-controller, html-helper

Long story short, I have about 73 selectlist elements on a single page in my ASP.Net MVC web app, all made with htmlhelpers. Their contents are in json files, so I populate these select lists with typescript. However, if I do that, the selected option is never saved as the value of the element.

I found a workaround, which is to bind the model to a hidden element, add listeners to the select list elements, and assign the selected option as the value of the hidden element.

The following is the result:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RFIModel.PSC, new { id = "PSC-Dropdown_Value" })

 @Html.DropDownList("PSC", new SelectList(" "), new { @class = "PSC-Dropdown PSC-Dropdown_Value" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RFIModel.PSC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RFIModel.PSC)
```

This is working, but again, it's a workaround and its annoying when you have 72 different elements on a page. I found that is I manually define the json in SelectList(), the select list itself gets the selected value, which would be awesome, but I really want to keep my json separated from my html.

```
@Html.DropDownList("PSC", new SelectList("[
        { "ID": "001", "Name": "Eurasian Collared-Dove" },
        { "ID": "002", "Name": "Bald Eagle" },
        { "ID": "003", "Name": "Cooper's Hawk" },
    ]"), new { @class = "PSC-Dropdown PSC-Dropdown_Value" })
```

So with this in mind, can't I just load the json into the SelectList()?

[I found a few examples here,](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/different-ways-bind-the-value-to-razor-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-mvc5/) but they aren't quite what I am looking for.

Comment: *"I really want to keep my json separated from my html."* - Where do you plan on keeping it and how will the code access it?  It's a big difference between providing the data server-side vs. fetching it client-side.

Comment: @David It will be client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment on the question above:

> It will be client side.

Then presumably somewhere in your JavaScript code you will have a reference to your JSON data.  Whether this is in the form of an object/array literal, an AJAX call, etc. doesn't really matter.  At some point you would have a variable which has your data.

In that case the [JSON Data example from the link you provided](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/different-ways-bind-the-value-to-razor-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-mvc5/) is what you're looking for.  Specifically look at how it populates the `<select>` element:

```
$(result).each(function() {  
    $("#FromJson").append($("<option></option>").val(this.ID).html(this.Name));  
});
```

In this case `result` is the variable which contains the JSON data (an array), and `$('#FromJson')` is the jQuery selector to identify the `<select>` element.  (Yours might be something like `$('#PSC')` or `$('#PSC-Dropdown')` depending on your HTML and how you'd specifically identify that element.)

Basically your server-side code would render an empty list:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PSC", new SelectList(), new { @class = "PSC-Dropdown PSC-Dropdown_Value" })
```

Then in your client-side code you'd populate the value from your JSON data.  The example on the link you provided uses jQuery's `$().each()`, though a simple loop would do the trick too:

```
for (let item of result) {
    $('#PSC').append($('<option/>').val(item.ID).html(item.Name));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  When I select an option, the selectlist element doesn't get the value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MARS: What do you mean by "doesn't get the value"?

Comment: When I submit the form, the value of the select list isn't passed to the controller. I even examined the element before and after selecting the option and it is not getting set the the value of the element.

Comment: @MARS: What is the resulting HTML of the `<select>` element?  Is the JavaScript code successfully appending the `<option>` elements in it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Its the same as your code, and I see all the options I need here.

Comment: @MARS: *"It is the same as your code"* - My answer contains no HTML.  What is the resulting HTML of the `<select>` element?  Specifically, does it have a `name` attribute?  Is it part of your `<form>`?  In your browser's debugging tools, when the `<form>` is posted, what is the data included for that HTTP request?

Comment: Sorry, here it is: <select class="PSC-Dropdown PSC-Dropdown_Value form-group form-control valid" id="PSC" name="PSC" aria-invalid="false">
<option disabled="">Select</option><option value="3312">Advance-Fee Loans, Credit Arrangers</option><option value="0242">Auto: Financing</option><option value="0225">Auto: Gas</option></select>

Comment: @MARS: That `<select>` would post its currently selected value as part of a `<form>`, associated with the key "PSC".  Do you have any other form elements with the same `name` attribute?  In your browser's debugging tools, in the network tab, when the form is posted, what keys/values of data are in the request?

Comment: There is only one PSC, and it's value is 3312 is I select the first option. I set a stop point in my controller that handles the request and PSC is null in the model data.

Comment: @MARS: A wide variety of causes could exist for this, so you're going to need to narrow it down.  Start by examining your browser's debugging tools.  (Chrome has good tools for this.)  On the Network tab you can observe all of the HTTP requests/responses.  (You may need to select an option to preserve the log if the page is reloading/navigating.)  In those network requests, find the POST for the form.  The request information should include any data sent as part of that request.  What is that data?

Comment: So I have other html helpers that handle form data. they look like this in the code:                                     @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RFIModel.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = " " } })
Maybe our select element isn't working because we aren't setting it to the model with x => x.RFIModel.PSC?

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is @David's, but I figured out how to bind the element to my model. I was using a viewmodel with several other models, and because of this, I needed to include the whole model in the name field, like so:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("RFIModel.PSC", new SelectList(" "), new { @class = "PSC-Dropdown PSC-Dropdown_Value" })
```

For other people, they may not need to do that, but anyway, `new SelectList(" ")` will create an empty dropdown element, and you can use @David's code to populate it with your json.